# Iterate in multiple states while rendering

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I'm trying to render a component that takes data from a local API and it's been set it into multiple states, at the moment I'm mapping through one state and I need to use some data from another state. How can I access this data and map through it once?

In `prodsLink={'https://www.sodimac.cl/sodimac-homy/product/' + skuData.productId + '/'}`

I need to render something like this:

`https://www.sodimac.cl/sodimac-homy/product/productID/productLocation`

but if I do this:

`prodsLink={'https://www.sodimac.cl/sodimac-homy/product/' + skuData.productId + '/' + this.state.ids.map(skuMarca => skuMarca.marca)}`

It will render something like this:

`https://www.sodimac.cl/sodimac-homy/product/productID/productLocation01,productLocation02,productLocation03,productLocation04`

UPDATE:

This is the output I'm looking for (once per loop not all of them in one array):

`<a href="https://www.sodimac.cl/sodimac-homy/product/productID/productLocation01"> BUTTON 01 </a>`

`<a href="https://www.sodimac.cl/sodimac-homy/product/productID/productLocation02"> BUTTON 02 </a>`

`<a href="https://www.sodimac.cl/sodimac-homy/product/productID/productLocation03"> BUTTON 03 </a>`

`<a href="https://www.sodimac.cl/sodimac-homy/product/productID/productLocation04"> BUTTON 04 </a>`

I know is confusing so here is my code.

```
render() {

    return (
      this.getWebServiceResponse(this.state.ids.map(e => e.sku).join('-'), 96),
      this.state.active == true &&
      <div className="row" style={{ width: '89%', margin: '0 auto' }}>
        <div className="blockCatPriceSlide">
          {this.state.products.map(skuData =>
              window.innerWidth > 440 && skuData.status === 'OK' ?
                <ContenidoUno
                  prodsName={skuData.name.substr(0, 30) + '...'}
                  prodsId={skuData.productId}
                  prodsStatus={skuData.status}
                  prodsPublished={skuData.published}
                  prodsNormal={skuData.NORMAL.toLocaleString().replace(',', '.')}
                  prodsCMR={skuData.CMR}
                  prodsCombo={skuData.combo}
                  prodsAhorro={skuData.savings}
                  prodsStock={skuData.stockLevel}
                  prodsAntes={skuData.NORMAL + skuData.savings > skuData.NORMAL ? <small> Antes: $ {skuData.NORMAL + skuData.savings} </small> : ''.toLocaleString().replace(',', '.')}
                  prodsLink={'https://www.sodimac.cl/sodimac-homy/product/' + skuData.productId + '/'}
                  prodsImg={'https://picsum.photos/g/570/250'}
                  prodsIcon={(skuData.combo === true &&
                    <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/100x50/f41435/ffffff?text=combo' className="iconic" alt="producto" />) ||
                    (skuData.CMR !== undefined && <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/100x50/f41435/ffffff?text=CMR' className="iconic" alt="producto" />)}
                  catName={skuData.webCategoryName}
                /> :
                <ContenidoUno
                  prodsName={'Producto sin información...'}
                  prodsId=''
                  prodsStatus=''
                  prodsPublished=''
                  prodsNormal=''
                  prodsCMR=''
                  prodsCombo=''
                  prodsAhorro=''
                  prodsStock=''
                  prodsAntes=''
                  prodsLink=''
                  prodsImg={'https://picsum.photos/g/570/250'}
                  prodsIcon=''
                  catName=''
                />

            )
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Array.prototype.map returns a new array, so in this situation you're just returning array of **[marca?, marca?, ...]**, so instead of returning, **marca?** from map you should returning whole link like so:

```
prodsLink={ this.state.ids.map(({ marca }) =>
  `https://www.sodimac.cl/sodimac-homy/product/${skuData.productId}/${marca}`
)}
```

this will generate link array:

[

`https://www.sodimac.cl/sodimac-homy/product/${skuData.productId}/${marca}`,
`https://www.sodimac.cl/sodimac-homy/product/${skuData.productId}/${marca}`,
`https://www.sodimac.cl/sodimac-homy/product/${skuData.productId}/${marca}`,

...

]

Comment: It's creating a link with all the links inside:

https://www.sodimac.cl/sodimac-homy/product/productID/marca,https://www.sodimac.cl/sodimac-homy/product/productID/marca,https://www.sodimac.cl/sodimac-homy/product/productID/marca,https://www.sodimac.cl/sodimac-homy/product/productID/marca

Comment: It's creating a link array, you should edit a question and specify what's your desired output.